# Mediacodec control the decoding progress

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to complete one simple player for audio and video with the MediaCodec and MediaExtractor,but found it hard to control and get  the progress when decoding and render, such as the functions seekTo(),getCurrentPositon() in the MediaPlayer.could someone have good tips?

Comment: What did you tried yet ? have you used any code snipped like this ?http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

Comment: Sorry,maybe i not describe the problem clearly,give one supplement.I used two thread to complete decode the audio and video source separatly,and render it with audioTrack and surface ,now i can't find the similar API like seekTo and getCurrentPosition ,so the progressBar seem to unusefull.The MediaExtractor have seekTo mothod ,but when i try seekTo(position),the audia and video only restart,not jumped to the specify position.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the MediaExtractor like this:

```
extractor.seekTo(seekPoint, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

where seekPoint is expressed in us, and represent the time from the start of the stream. For audio seek, I would recommend first to perform the video seek and then, at the first decoded video frame, read the extractor time:

```
extractor.getSampleTime();
```

and use it for audio seek. This allows for better audio-video sync, as video will seek to closest seek which may be several seconds away from the desired seek point, while audio will usually have much smaller granulation.